# LATEX question about logical symbol

Tags: support, mathjax

For the "entailment" relation we have $\models$ (\models or \vDash).

Sometimes I need "logical equivalence", sometimes symbolized as "=||=".

*Question* : where I can find $\leftmodels$ or one of its equivalent ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `$=\hspace{-.5em}||\hspace{-.5em}=$`

$=\hspace{-.5em}||\hspace{-.5em}=$

Comment: Good, thanks :)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If not required for Mathjax, see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114364/what-command-to-use-for-reversed-vdash) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198346/symbol-for-defined-to-be-logically-equivalent-%E2%87%94).

Comment: Why not $=\hspace{-.5em}|\models$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila On my display the spacing of `=\hspace{-.5em}|\models` is wider than the answer. Not sure if that is wanted.

Comment: You may want to put your symbol inside `\mathrel{...}` so that it acts as a relation (and as a unit rather then several separate characters).